# Merge objects from two different type arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, lodash

imagine that, we have two arrays. Each of the containing objects of different type. For example:

```
let first: Foo[] = [
    { a: 12, b: 'x', c: 0 },
    { a: 43, b: 'y', c: 0 }
];

let second: number[] = [11, 15];
```

I would like merge theirs objects in a way that I finally get one array looks like below:

```
let first: Foo[] = [
    { a: 12, b: 'x', c: 11 },
    { a: 43, b: 'y', c: 15 }
];
```

As you can see I just want to assign value from the second array to `c` property of object from first array.

I hope that you understand my explanation of problem. I believe in your skills, guys!

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Is it just me or is this question posted at least twice an hour?

Comment: @sjahan Please provide at least one duplicate, I will appreciate it.

Comment: Why so many down votes? I suppose that you see my question duplicated, but why don't you link to similar threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could `zip` the two arrays into one,

```
const first: Foo[] = [
    { a: 12, b: 'x', c: 0 },
    { a: 43, b: 'y', c: 0 }
];

const second: number[] = [11, 15];

const result: Foo[] = first.map((e, i) => {
    return <Foo>Object.assign({}, e, { c: second[i] });
});
```

Comment: Of cause this solution is straightforward and working. But what happens if one next time needs to *zip* to `b` or `a` or some key one does not know because it is generic at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

As so often, `Array.prototype.reduce` provides a good base for an approach like e.g. this one ...

```js
var listOfItems = [
  { a: 12, b: 'x', c: 0 },
  { a: 43, b: 'y', c: 0 }
];
var listOfValues = [11, 15];


function reassignValueToGivenKey(collector, item, idx) {
  item = Object.assign({}, item); // do not mutate original reference.
  item[collector.key] = collector.valueList[idx]; // reassign value.
  collector.itemList.push(item); // collect processed items separately.
  return collector;
}

var result = listOfItems.reduce(reassignValueToGivenKey, {

  key: 'c',
  valueList: listOfValues,
  itemList: []
  
}).itemList;

console.log('listOfItems : ', listOfItems);
console.log('result : ', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do it like this...
Maybe not the best, but should work in you case :)
This is very simple...

```
for(var i in second){
   var elem = second[i];
   first[i]['c'] = elem;
}
```